# Migration of Sharepoint Masterpages to ASP.NET Masterpages

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, master-pages

Is it possible to convert / migrate **Sharepoint Masterpages** to **ASP.NET Masterpages** ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It can't see why anyone would want to do that.. you might as well take some of the HTML that isn't terrible, some of the CSS and Images and start new..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to Remove all the SharePoint Related Controls & Reference out the Master Page, that is the only thing you will have to do to get the Master Page work in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing, but with a lot of SharePoint specific controls/placeholders and a horrible structure with lots of nested tables. Definitely possible, but not something I would recommend.